# BeautifulSoup; grabbing text in a span class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape prices from a website [html format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymTv5.png) You can see that the price is a #Text in the end of span. Here is my code:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'pass')).text
    # have soup parse the html
    soup = bs(response, 'html.parser')
    # loop over the content
    for object in soup.find_all(class_='product__price'):
        print(object)
```

I am getting this for the output:

```
<span class="product__price">
<div hidden="">
<pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr">
<small>/home/aks/zcCat/storage/framework/views/d5dcf7ffe999e06408f2eb37d269f82a154f3099.php:81:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=14)</i>
  'itemID' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color="#4e9a06">975</font>
  'name' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Complete Set of 14 GM Double-Sided VATS Keys (BlueRocket)'</font> <i>(length=57)</i>
  'modelName' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'BRK-VATS-DS-SET'</font> <i>(length=15)</i>
  'manufacturerName' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'BlueRocket'</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
  'image' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'975_BRK-VATS-DS-SET_082020.jpg'</font> <i>(length=30)</i>
  'rating' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color="#4e9a06">0</font>
  'price' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>float</small> <font color="#f57900">57.5</font>
  'qtyMin' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color="#4e9a06">1</font>
  'qtyOrder' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color="#4e9a06">1</font>
  'inStock' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>boolean</small> <font color="#75507b">true</font>
  'new' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>boolean</small> <font color="#75507b">false</font>
  'categoryName' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'GM'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
  'customData' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font>
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=19)</i>
      'cross_ref' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'KLF-VAT2-BUNDLE (UHS), VATS DOUBLE BUNDLE, B-82 Curtis B82 ESP B82 Ilco B82 Jet B82 Orion B82 Hillman GM74 
Lotus GM37 Silca 1707 B'</font> <i>(length=130)</i>
      'ekey' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'filter_option' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Automotive_'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
      'frequency' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'product_condition' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Aftermarket'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
      'product_make' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Buick_Chevrolet_Oldsmobile_'</font> <i>(length=27)</i>
      'product_type' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Mechanical Key'</font> <i>(length=14)</i>
      'products_cost' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'46.8000'</font> <i>(length=7)</i>
      'products_discount_type' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'products_dropshipped' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'products_group_a_price' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0.0000'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
      'products_group_b_price' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0.0000'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
      'products_group_c_price' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0.0000'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
      'products_group_d_price' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0.0000'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
      'products_group_e_price' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'57.5000'</font> <i>(length=7)</i>
      'products_secret' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'products_status_reason' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'AVAILABLE'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
      'shell' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
      'show_remotes' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'0'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
  'isBundle' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>boolean</small> <font color="#75507b">false</font>
</pre>
</div>
$57.50
</span>
```

I've tried separate soup.find for text and other avenues. I've tried regex for $. I've tried returning the strings but that gives me the entire hidden div above. I just need the price text. Any ideas are welcome, I am trying to keep this as dynamic as possible. TIA

Answer (score 0):

If the price is always last element before the closing tag, you can use `.contents[-1]`:

```py
print(soup.select_one(".product__price").contents[-1].strip())
```

Prints:

```
$57.50
```

OR:

Remove the `<div hidden="">` tag and get the text:

```py
soup.select_one("div[hidden]").extract()
print(soup.select_one(".product__price").text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
$57.50
```